# Python: readline() until hex 0D 0A 0D 0A (two linefeed+carriage return) appear

Tags: python, nginx, hex

I want to read NGINX cache files and extract the "KEY:" and the HTTP header.

I have achieved reading the KEY: of the nginx cache file by analyzing several nginx cache files in a hex editor. I saw that the KEY: always starts at 0x00000150. See screenshot of one nginx cache file:
[image]

My current code is:

```py
import os

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
        f.seek(0x00000150)    # skip nginx identification header
        key_magic = f.read(6)
        if key_magic != '\nKEY: ':
            raise ValueError('Not a cache file: ' + str(file_path))
        key = f.readline()[:-1]  

def main():
    nginx_cache_path = "/usr/share/nginx/cache/"

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(nginx_cache_path):
        for file in files:
            process_file(path + '/' + file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, I read the whole KEY: line by just doing readline().

Now, my next goal is to read the HTTP header of the cache file. They appear after the KEY: with a line feed (0A) and end with two line feed + carriage returns (0D 0A 0D 0A).
See screenshot from hex editor:

[image]

My goal:

- I want to read everything between the end of KEY: (the beginning after the 0A, as marked in the screenshot) and until the first time two "0D 0A" appear. The two times "0D 0A" is important, because the HTTP header itself have "0D 0A", but not two times, only once for each new line. How can I do this?

What I know so far:

- After the value of KEY:, it does a linefeed (0A) once.
- The HTTP header length is unknown.
- The HTTP header contain 0D 0A several times but always only once in this combination, like (AA AA AA AA **0D 0A** AA AA AA AA ...) and never two times.
- When the HTTP header section ends, it ends with two line feed+carriage returns. (0D 0A 0D 0A). And this is where I want to stop reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the whole file to memory you could find the ending position of the KEY then use find

```py
end_position = hex_string.find(bytes.fromhex('0D0A0D0A'), key_end_position)
```

If you can't read the whole file to memory you would have to read step by step, whichever buffer size you use you should probably store previous previous read, previous read and current read to avoid reading the string you're looking for in 2 consecutive read and missing it.

Would this work? I have no idea.

```py
last_three = ['', '', '']
text_to_find = bytes.fromhex('0D0A0D0A')
found_position = 0
while True:
    chunk = f.read(4096)
    if not chunk:
        break
    
    current_file_position = f.tell()
    last_three.append(chunk)
    last_three = last_three[-3]
    text_to_search = last_three.join('')

    position = text_to_search.find(text_to_find)

    if position != -1:
        extra_length = len(last_three) - position + len(text_to_find)
        found_position = current_file_position - len(last_three)
        break
```